# tableView functions not getting called by iPhone

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview

I have a database application in xcode which populates the rows in a tableview from data collected from the SQLite database. This works 100% perfectly in my simulator,

However when i run the application on my iPhone (IOS 6.1.2), the three functions that would populate the table view are never called so the list stays blank. The functions are

numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath

any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only reason those functions wouldn't be called is if your view controller isn't a datasource/delegate of tableview-have your stepped through your class to make sure they aren't being called when run on your device? because more likely the issue would be with the database that would result in no data to be displayed

Comment: no everything is fine with the database,i have put NSLogs in the functions, when the simulator runs all the functions are called, however when it is run on the iphone these functions are not called, all the delegates and data sources are set up correctly

Comment: Are you sure that your view controller is being called for your tableview, then?  Is the tableview the initial screen of the application, i.e. is there some logic gate in your app delegate that would lead to possibly not calling the view controller?  If nothing else is changing except the device(and you are positive there are no issues with the database)then this would be the only other option

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I figured it out, you guys where right there was an issue with the database, I pulled the tables off the phone that get created and sure enough the table in question kept corrupting, it never corrupted in the simulator though, to solve this I changed my code slightly so all tables that I needed where created at the same time when the app loaded. This corrected the issue of my databse corrupting, im assuming they corrupted as I tried to create new tables further along in the application and this seemed to corrupt the tables in the phone.

Comment: So basically the lesson I learned is plan all the tables and databases that you need before writing the application, and then create them all at the same time to eradicate any issues :D cheers for the advice